# Fixed width div

Tags: html, position, css-position

I set my div to be fixed position and when I scroll page to very bottom or if I use smaller screen like smartphone or tablet my fixed div float over my footer. How can I fix this?

This is my fixed div:

```
.infoItem{
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px #e4e4e4 solid;
    width: 227px;
    background:#f8f6f7;
    position: fixed;
}
```

and this is my wrapper:

```
.wrapper { 
  min-width:954px;
}
```

I also try to wrap my `infoteam` div in another div and set new div to be `position: absolute` but that also didn't work.

Fixed div html

```
<div class="box-collateral box-up-sell">

        <div class="infoItem">
            <p class="heading">Add to your </p>
            <p class="content">

                        <div class='upsellContainer'>

                               <div>

                               </div>
                        </div>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

footer css

```
.footer { background:url(../images/footer-top-border.png) repeat-x;}
/* .footer-container { border-top:15px solid #b6d1e2; }*/

.footer { width:904px; margin:0 auto; padding:30px 10px 50px; }
.footer .store-switcher { display:inline; margin:0 5px 0 0; color:#fff; }
.footer .store-switcher label { font-weight:bold; vertical-align:middle; }
.footer .store-switcher select { padding:0; vertical-align:middle; }
.footer a {text-decoration:none; }
.footer a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
.footer .bugs { margin:13px 0 0; }
.footer .bugs a { text-decoration:underline; }
.footer .bugs a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
.footer address { margin:0 0 20px; }
.footer address a {text-decoration:underline; }
.footer address a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
.footer ul { display:inline; }
.footer ul.links { display:block; }
.footer li {  background:url(../images/bkg_pipe2.gif) 100% 60% no-repeat; padding:0 7px 0 4px; }
.footer li.last { background:none !important; padding-right:0 !important; }
.footer-container .bottom-container { margin:0 0 5px; }
```

Comment: Can I see the CSS for your footer? And maybe the HTML for the wrapper, header and footer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your html look like? Can you provide a screenshot of the actual problem?

Comment: is there a specific reason you have fixed a div with content in it. This will adjust its height according to content and naturally overflow anything under it. 

You could try a more stable layout practice by floating divs or using inline elements like 960.gs

Comment: @Ran Your edits are bad. Please stop bolding random phrases while ignoring glaring punctuation, spelling and grammar errors. Your edits are not helping anybody, they're making work for other editors. You're also using backticks to highlight words. Don't do that, backticks are for inline code.

Answer (score 0):

Add another div right after your div and before your footer like this:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

This will force any element below it down. You also want to make sure that the footer has `clear:both` as well (this should always be true of footers)

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear:both` inside the `footer div` or apply clear:both in css like:

```
#footer{
  clear: both;
}
```